# How URLs are write once?

Tags: java, url

I was going through java.net package and [read this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/creatingUrls.html):

> URLs are "write-once" objects. Once you've created a URL object, you
>   cannot change any of its attributes (protocol, host name, filename, or
>   port number).

But, if we look into the java.net.URL we will find this:

```
protected void set(String protocol, String host,
                       int port, String file, String ref)
```

and

```
protected void set(String protocol, String host, int port,
                       String authority, String userInfo, String path,
                       String query, String ref)
```

So, I know these are **protected** methods but these can be accessed via

```
public static void setURLStreamHandlerFactory(URLStreamHandlerFactory fac)
```

So, my question is, if that statement I quoted on top is vague or I just misunderstood it?

Comment: Please provide a link to your quote "URLs are write-once...". So we can better understand the context

Comment: Look at the very bottom of this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/creatingUrls.html

Comment: The question is probably better asked, "is it appropriate to use a contrived `URLStreamHandler` to mutate fields that are otherwise immutable?"  Unless you are doing something in the spirit of `URLStreamHandler`'s purpose, the answer is probably no.

Comment: Contrast with the `URI`class, which is properly immutable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URLs are "write-once" objects by **you** (who are just using `URL` objects). You can't modify them.

`URL`s have to be created and initialized internally, sometime, so *someone* has to modify them. Optimally this would have to be done in its constructor, but that would lose flexibility. `URL`s can point to a variaty of objects and the implementation to access and handle them is not restricted to the standard library, you can write implementations to handle custom protocols.

Btw, in Java 8 they are not `protected`, but package private which is even more restrictive (but not that it really matters since `URL` class is declared `final` anyway so you cannot subclass it).

**Edit: Example**

The URL class has many constructors: some allows you to specify different parts of the URL like protocol, host, port etc., and there are some which allows you to specify the URL as one `String`: `spec`.

In the latter case (if URL is specified as one `String`), the different parts of the URL (protocol, host, port etc.) has to be parsed from the `String`. This parsing is done by a [`URLStreamHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html) which when done parsing the `String` in the implementation of the [`URLStreamHandler.parseURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html#parseURL-java.net.URL-java.lang.String-int-int-) method have to use the `URL.set()` method to set the different parts "back" to the `URL` class because the fields holding these parts are `private` and there are no setter methods for them.

Since the parsing is done in another class (`URLStreamHandler`), `URL` provides a non-public method to receive the parsing result. This provides flexibility as you can replace/extend the `URLStreamHandler` but still allows `URL` to be declared `final` and be "write-once".

Comment: You said, you can't modify them, right? But I am in control of URLStreamHandler and I can modify it via this, no?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But if you don't mind, can you give me a scenario? I mean, if there is some scenario, I might be able to understand it better.

Comment: @Mr.777 Added more explanaion.

Comment: Thnx a lot for explaination

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the official documentation (net/URL.html) for the "set" methods

> Sets the fields of the URL. This is not a public method so that only URLStreamHandlers can modify URL fields. **URLs are otherwise constant**.

The "otherwise" makes me think that only the 2 "set" methods can modify an URL object, and you cannot modify it using any other operation other than a "set" method. They are an exception ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for the Class URL, there are `public` Getters (eg `getPort`) but no Setter methods. The `set` method is protected and cannot be accessed from outside the package.

You can reassign a URL object though, provided that your object isn't final.

e.g.

```
URL url1 = new URL ("http://www.example1");
URL url2 = new URL ("http://www.example2");

url1 = url2;
```

I think that the statement that you provide from the documentation is very vague

Comment: Thanks... Thats what i said